# Using list elements as variable names in Python

Tags: python

I'm guessing this will be a really simple problem but I have no solution yet.

I have a long code that does modelling and updates values of variables for optimisation. The code is initially written like this:

```
init_old(x,y):
    return {(k):olddict[k][x][0]*prod[y] for k in realnames}

Q_house=init_old(“Q_house”,"P_house")
Q_car=init_old(“Q_car”,"P_car")
Q_holiday=init_old(“Q_holiday”,"P_holiday")
```

I already can simplify it a bit with a comprehension:

```
ListOfExpenses=["house","car","holiday"]
Q_house, Q_car, Q_holiday=[init_old(“Q_”+i,"P0_"+i) for i in ListOfExpenses]
```

I am trying to find an equivalent but more flexible way of writing that final line, so that I change the list of Expenses and the "Q_..." variables together easily:

```
ListOfExpenses=["house","car","holiday"]
ListOfCost=["Q_house","Q_car","Q_holiday"]
Elements_Of_ListOfCost=[init_old(“Q_”+i,"P0_"+i) for i in ListOfExpenses]
```

So when I look for Q_house, Q_car or Q_holiday later, it returns the  same `Q_house=init_old(“Q_house”,"P_house")` calculated in the original code.

I don't want to use dictionaries for now as they would require major change to the rest of the code and calling dictionaries causes problems in some of the other functions. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Dictionaries are what you would use. Anything else would be emulating one, because you need something that maps keys to values. How does your other code break?

Comment: Python developers have obviously designed an easier way of approaching your intention. Trying to create your own kind of dictionary is not a good idea. If you cannot implement a dictionary instead of that is that you have coded it completely wrong. You perceive this when you start to have the need of using way too complex stuff for something as simple as dictionaries.

Comment: I really recommend you to completely re-structure your code. Your problem is not trying to create something that already exists based in something you've done, but creating something you can do based in something that already exists.

Comment: Ok, quickly replying to this. I'm trying to simplify a code that was written by others and before trying to re-write the whole thing I just want to make sure that there isn't a simpler way of solving it.

Comment: You are probably right though. At the moment a lot of interdependent functions are looking for this Q_car,.. variables and fail. Later they are included in other dictionaries and in constraint functions used to by the optimiser. Defining those from dictionaries seems already complicated. Basically I didn't completely decipher the code yet, but maybe that is the only thing to do.